# makefile to compile multiple sources, with different flags

Tags: c++, c, gcc, makefile

I have the following makefile:

```
CC = gcc
SRC = source1.c
EXE = source1
FLAGS = -fopenmp

all: $(src)
$(CC) -o $(EXE) $(SRC) $(FLAGS)

clean:
rm $(EXE)
```

How can I modify it so I can use multiple sources, some of them compiled with the flag -fopenmp, some of them compiled without. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should get you started: Note how `-fopenmp` gets added just for source2.c

```
CC=gcc
SRC=source1.c source2.c
OBJ=$(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SRC))
EXE=source1
FLAGS= -g -O2

source2.o: FLAGS+=-fopenmp

all: $(EXE)

$(EXE): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(FLAGS)

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $^ $(FLAGS)

clean:
    rm $(EXE)$
```

Output of `make -Bsn`:

```
gcc -o source1.o source1.c -g -O2
gcc -o source2.o source2.c -g -O2 -fopenmp
gcc -o source1 source1.o source2.o -g -O2
```

Comment: Spotted missing -c flag. Fixed

Answer (score 0):

You can define for example, `EXTFLAGS=$(FLAGS) -fopenmp`, and use `EXTFLAGS` for some rules.